# What is the outcome of hiding "_V" (versionKey) field in Mongoose (Mongodb)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We can hide this field using many ways like this one:

```
let schema = new Schema({ },{versionKey: false});
```

But I want to know the outcome and the effect of hiding this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey) and on that great [article](http://aaronheckmann.tumblr.com/post/48943525537/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning)

---

Some answer here :

The versionKey is used by mongoose to know about conflict access on documents.
The versionKey is incremented after each modification.

So if two process retrieve the document in version 2, and then modify the document and try to `.save()`, the first process will succeed and versionKey will be incremented to 3. The second process will have it's request denied; because the document with versionKey equals to 2 do not exist anymore.